# WordPress doesn’t load css, image and js files after moving local installation folder

Tags: theme-development, css

I am running Wordpress on my local machine using WAMPServer. However, after moving the WordPress files from a folder called, **wamp64/www/custom_theme/** to the **wamp64/www** folder, WP is still attempting to load images, CSS and js files from the previous (now deleted) folder.

I am using

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'travelagencytheme-bs-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

to load the css.

To load the javascript, I'm using

```
wp_enqueue_script('travelagencytheme-tether', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/tether.min.js', array(), '20170115', true);
wp_enqueue_script('travelagencytheme-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '20170915', true);
```

Comment: Have you changed WP's home and site url (`home`, `site_url` in wp_options)?

Comment: Also when you move a site you need to update the htaccess file to reference the home directory, based on your example your htaccess needs to point to wamp64/www not wamp64/www/custom_theme. And don't forget WordPress theme always requires at least a style.css file to run properly.